# Error- AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim in autoencoder design in keras

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am a newbie in Python 3.5. I am trying to program a simple auto-encoder which will train on a data-set of 60 images of apple and try to reconstruct the image given in the root. I have used the following codes :

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = Image.open('C:\Python35\Scripts\apple.jpg')
encoding_dim = 32
input_img = Input(shape=(65536,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(65536, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"C:\Users\vlsi\Desktop\train",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
autoencoder.fit(train_generator,
                epochs=2,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True)
encoded_img = encoder.predict(np.array(image))
decoded_img = decoder.predict(encoded_img)
plt.imshow(decoded_img)
```

It gives an error

> AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Keras `fit` function takes arrays of data, numpy arrays, not generators. The function you need is `fit_generator`. Note that  `fit_generator` takes slightly different parameters, such as `steps_per_epoch` instead of `batch_size`.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate a little please. I tried your idea using

Comment: @mrin9san Elaborate on what exactly? Your comment seems incomplete.

Comment: Hi, I changed the program with fit_generator function. I am having an issue now. Seems the issue is with dimensionality mismatch.                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790068/value-error-with-dimensions-in-designing-a-simple-autoencoder

Comment: You can also include a tf dataset which can be fed by an iterator.

Comment: @DUWUDA Thanks for your advice. I shall look onto it.

Comment: Following the TF Documentation, this answer is the exact opposite of what should be done (At present time). More info here: [TF Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: @FedericoDorato Again, this question is about keras, not tf.keras, your comment is misleading and does not consider that they are two different libraries

Comment: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method According to the documentation, the `fit`methods accepts a generator input. There is also no `fit_generator`method in keras.

Comment: @Benson_YoureFired that   only applies to tf.keras, this answer is for keras which is not the same library. Look at the date of the answer too.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but i'm running into the same issue. I'm using keras and looked at the keras doc at the link but couldn't fix it.

Comment: @Benson_YoureFired open your own question