# Tensorflow 1.9.0: A question about training my model with generators

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generator, tf.keras

## Situation

I am trying to build my own CNN with images I compiled.
I have two folders with training and validation data. This is my code so far:

```py
import os
import sys
import shutil
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

SCRIPT_DIR = os.getcwd()

TRAIN_GRAPH = 'training_graph.pb'
CHKPT_FILE = 'float_model.ckpt'

CHKPT_DIR = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'chkpts')
TB_LOG_DIR = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'tb_logs')
CHKPT_PATH = os.path.join(CHKPT_DIR, CHKPT_FILE)
CNN_DIR = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'cnn_dir')

# create a directory for the dataset if it doesn't already exist
if not (os.path.exists(CNN_DIR)):
    os.makedirs(CNN_DIR)
    print("Directory " , CNN_DIR ,  "created ") 

# create a directory for the TensorBoard data if it doesn't already exist
# delete it and recreate if it already exists
if (os.path.exists(TB_LOG_DIR)):
    shutil.rmtree(TB_LOG_DIR)
os.makedirs(TB_LOG_DIR)
print("Directory " , TB_LOG_DIR ,  "created ") 

# create a directory for the checkpoint if it doesn't already exist
# delete it and recreate if it already exists
if (os.path.exists(CHKPT_DIR)):
    shutil.rmtree(CHKPT_DIR)
os.makedirs(CHKPT_DIR)
print("Directory " , CHKPT_DIR ,  "created ")

LEARN_RATE = 0.0001
BATCHSIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 10
IMG_SIZE = 224

# ===== IMPORTANT PART STARTS HERE ================================

# SETTING UP DATA ---------------
datagen_training = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)

dataset_training = datagen_training.flow_from_directory(
        "./dataset/prepared/training",
        target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
        batch_size = BATCHSIZE,
        class_mode = "binary")

datagen_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

dataset_test = datagen_training.flow_from_directory(
        "./dataset/prepared/validation",
        target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
        batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
        class_mode="binary")
# SETTING UP CNN ---------------

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# First convolutional layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters = 16, 
    kernel_size = 3, 
    activation = tf.nn.relu, 
    input_shape = [IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3]))

# Maxpooling layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(
    pool_size = 2, 
    strides = 2))

# Second convolutional layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters = 32, 
    kernel_size = 3, 
    activation = tf.nn.relu))
  
# Flattening the vector
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
        
# Fully connected layer #1
# Hidden layer with 256 neurons
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units = 256,
    activation = tf.keras.activations.softmax))

# Fully connected layer #2
# Densing down to 8 variables, output layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units = 8,
    activation = None))

cnn.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])

# PROBLEM LIES HERE ------------------------
cnn.fit(x = dataset_training, 
    validation_data = dataset_test,
    epochs = 10)
```

When I execute this, I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 cnn.fit(x = dataset_training,
> 2     validation_data = dataset_test,
> ----> 3     epochs = 10)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> **kwargs)    1261         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',    1262         steps=steps_per_epoch,
> -> 1263         validation_split=validation_split)    1264     1265     # Prepare validation data.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
> batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
> 866         feed_input_shapes,
> 867         check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
> --> 868         exception_prefix='input')
> 869
> 870     if y is not None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
> exception_prefix)
> 141     data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
> 142     data = [data]
> --> 143   data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
> 144
> 145   if len(data) != len(names):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in (.0)
> 141     data = data.values if data.**class**.**name** == 'DataFrame' else data
> 142     data = [data]
> --> 143   data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
> 144
> 145   if len(data) != len(names):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in standardize_single_array(x)
> 79   elif tensor_util.is_tensor(x):
> 80     return x
> ---> 81   elif x.ndim == 1:
> 82     x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
> 83   return x
>
> AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

The tutorial I am following probably uses a more recent version of Tensorflow. However, due to restrictions in my system I need to use the version I am using. Now [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779602/error-attributeerror-directoryiterator-object-has-no-attribute-ndim-in-auto/52780095) SO post, I need to use `fit_generator(...)`. Looking at [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keras-fit-and-keras-fit_generator/) the syntax of `fit_generator(...)` is:

```py
fit_generator(object, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs = 1,
  verbose = getOption("keras.fit_verbose", default = 1),
  callbacks = NULL, view_metrics = getOption("keras.view_metrics",
  default = "auto"), validation_data = NULL, validation_steps = NULL,
  class_weight = NULL, max_queue_size = 10, workers = 1,
  initial_epoch = 0)
```

Which means, I need to give the function a generator. However, the example given in the post looks like this:

```py
# performing data argumentation by training image generator
dataAugmentaion = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 30, zoom_range = 0.20, 
fill_mode = "nearest", shear_range = 0.20, horizontal_flip = True, 
width_shift_range = 0.1, height_shift_range = 0.1)

# training the model
model.fit_generator(dataAugmentaion.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size = 32),
 validation_data = (testX, testY), steps_per_epoch = len(trainX) // 32,
 epochs = 10)
```

Which is weird for me. Where does the `trainX` and `trainY` come from? I don't have variables like that, because I (don't seem to) have some kind of vector of input and output data, at least it's not obvious for me where those arrays/vectors/tuples come from.
I also noticed in another example from Avnet, that they also get such kind of data:

```
mnist_dataset = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data('mnist_data')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist_dataset
```

I don't get what is in those arrays, how that data is formatted, and what to use them for. I understand that I need some kind of input vector/image, which, in my code, should be provided by the `ImageDataGenerator`, right? There seems to be a big thing I am missing to understand how this works. The tutorial I am following doesn't elaborate further on this, since they can just plug in the generators into `cnn.fit(...)`.

---

## Questions

**So I guess my questions are the following:**

1. What are those arrays like `trainX` and `trainY` or `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`?
2. What do I need them for?
3. How are they formatted?
4. How can I extract the data in that format from my `ImageDataGenerator` or rather from the `DirectoryIterator` which I use to "load" my data with `flow_from_directory(...)` (here: `dataset_training` and `dataset_test`)
5. Any other recommendations or suggestions for my code/methodology?

**Tensorflow Version: 1.9.0**

**Keras Version: 2.1.6-tf**

---

## Update

According to [this post](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), the function `fit_generator(...)` should look a bit like this:

```
# ...
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
# ...
```

I changed the `fit` into `fit_generator`. Which basically results in this:

```py
cnn.fit_generator(
        generator=datagen_training,
        steps_per_epoch=50000/32,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=datagen_test,
        validation_steps=800
)
```

Unfortunately, that throws this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 9         epochs=EPOCHS,
> 10         validation_data=datagen_test,
> ---> 11         validation_steps=800
> 12 )
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose,
> callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight,
> max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
> 1759         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,    1760
> shuffle=shuffle,
> -> 1761         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)    1762     1763   def evaluate_generator(self,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/decent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose,
> callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight,
> max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
> 112     if do_validation and not val_gen:
> 113       # Prepare data for validation
> --> 114       if len(validation_data) == 2:
> 115         val_x, val_y = validation_data  # pylint: disable=unpacking-non-sequence
> 116         val_sample_weight = None
>
> TypeError: object of type 'ImageDataGenerator' has no len()

Comment: which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot to write that down. My version is 1.9.0 and I can't upgrade, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh wait, I **did** write it in the title.

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge is limited, and I'm sure someone else will come along to solve.  However, the ImageDataGenerator class would seem to be a good fit - creating a ready-made and customizable generator object for fit_generator() method - basically yielding subsets of the input tensors to optimize processing in batches.

Look to use [ImageDataGenerator's flow()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow) method since you are already pre-processing your image data in code (assuming that's all done effectively).  `flow_from_directory()` is a good off-the-shelf solution if you haven't set up loading and preprocessing and have images in a folder.

Something like this might get you started (default parameters used, and some arbitrary batch/step values):

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator() #Using rescale=1./255 (for 8 bit images) will optimize your model's performance
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator() #Using rescale=1./255 (for 8 bit images) will optimize your model's performance

train_generator = train_datagen.flow( dataset_training, batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')
val_generator = val_datagen.flow( dataset_test, batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')

history = cnn.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                            steps_per_epoch=100,
                            epochs=10,
                            validation_data=val_generator,
                            validation_steps=50)
```

Whether that takes you to next step is uncertain, but you'll want to save the history object - it retains data for 'acc', 'val_acc', 'loss', and 'val_loss'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, unfortunately that only brings up another issue, which I've addressed in the "update".

Comment: Right, the (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) will vary depending on the types of images you're looking at, but correspond to (training subset image tensors, validation subset image tensors), (training image labels - 0/1 for binary classifications, validation image labels).  The "Y" or label inputs default to None if none are provided - depending on your data you may want to go back to processing and ensure you have those arrays all set up

Comment: Aah okay that makes sense. Where do I get them from? Can I extract them from the `ImageDataGenerator` or something? Or do I have to set up the labels manually?

Comment: For training and validation yes you'd need to have the labels set up with some type of manual process.  It can be entering those "true/false" 0/1 values in a single column in a csv table and then reading that, but easiest/most common is having folders with only specifically labeled images.  Classic example is having a folder full of dog photos, and a folder full of cat photos, and creating an array with all 0s or all 1s when each is read to memory - then zipping that in with the filenames or associated pixel arrays.